# how to make shorthand commands using phing

Tags: build-automation, phing

Suppose I have an executable for, e. g. Behat (doesn't matter, though) inside `vendor/bin/` under root of my codebase. Its config lies under `build/configs/`and the test specs lie under `tests/suites/acceptance/`. All this directories are under root of codebase.

So, invocation of Behat for a single spec called `featurename` would be:

```
vendor/bin/behat --config build/configs/behat.yml tests/suites/acceptance/featurename.feature
```

With Phing this can be collapsed to:

```
phing spec featurename
```

However, my question is: **how to pass other behat's commandline arguments using the phing shorthand command?** Like that:

```
phing spec featurename -- -f html -p profilename --no-colors
```

Everything after `--` expected to be passed to Behat verbatim.

Note, **I am using Behat only as an example**, I have other executables to wrap the similar way. I remember that some programs from GNU did that but don't remember which now.

Is this even possible? Do I need to recreate the whole interface of Behat inside the task definition to do this?

P. S. I had a hard time trying to formulate the question title, so feel free to edit it to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough, you can pass arguments to Phing using `-D<property>=<value>` but yes, you'd probably need to incorporate all that into your task definition.

http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/apas02.html

Comment: Okay... :( Pretty inconvenient.